# Uploading files with multer (nodeJs) doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, multer

I'm trying to upload multiples files with a modal that contains a form with an input.

My modal (jade template format) :

```
#modalAddFile.modal
    form#uploadForm(enctype='multipart/form-data', action='/#{category}/addFiles', method='post')
      .modal-content
        .file-field.input-field
          .btn
            span Ajouter
            input(type='file', name='songs', multiple)
          .file-path-wrapper
            input.file-path.validate(type='text')

      .modal-footer
        a#cancel.modal-action.modal-close.waves-effect.waves-red.btn-flat(href='#!') Annuler
        button#addFile.modal-action.modal-close.waves-effect.waves-green.btn-flat(type='submit', name='action', href='#!') Valider
```

routes.js :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
//Upload file
var multer  = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest: '../public/test/' });

//Add files
router.post('/:category/addFiles', upload.array('songs'), function (req, res, next) {
  res.redirect('/');
});

module.exports = router;
```

I don't have any apparent error (200 success), I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Why do you use `upload.array('songs')` instead of `upload.any()`?

Comment: There is no particular reason, but I've also tried with  `upload.any()`, it doesn't resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var multer  = require('multer');
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, '../public/test/')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname)
    }
});
var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

//Add files
router.post('/:category/addFiles', upload.any(), function (req, res, next) {
  res.redirect('/');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: This server-code works correct for me in `NodeJS 5.7.1` Try to set `console.log` before `res.redirect('/')` to make sure that this route is work. And make sure you have permissions to write in `../public/test/` directory

Comment: The log appears in my console (the route works fine).
I've set my folder to 777 permission, so I don't know what more to do ... :/

EDIT : I changed the path to absolute path, and it's working know.